# How to ReadBuffer several times for WriteBuffer

Tags: delphi

Although the value of the bbuf and hbuff is different but nothing happening for the `hdevi`.

```
var
  bfile:    TFileStream;
  hdevi:    TFileStream;
  bbuff:    array[0..511] of byte;
  hbuff:    array[0..87039] of byte;
  curr:     string;
  i:        integer;
begin
  curr:=GetCurrentDir;
  hdevi := TFileStream.Create(PChar(deviceno), fmOpenReadWrite);
  try
    bfile := TFileStream.Create(PChar(curr+'\bfile'), fmOpenReadWrite);
    try
      hdevi.ReadBuffer(hbuff[0],length(hbuff));
      bfile.ReadBuffer(bbuff[0],length(bbuff));
      hdevi.WriteBuffer(bbuff[0],length(bbuff));
      //for i:=0 to length(bbuff)-1 do
      //ShowMessage(IntToHex(hbuff[i],2)+'-'+IntToHex(bbuff[i],2));
    finally
      bfile.Free;
    end
  finally
    hdevi.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But it work after the following line is removed

```
hdevi.ReadBuffer(hbuff[0],length(hbuff));
```

or add this line `hdevi.Position:=0;` before

```
hdevi.WriteBuffer(bbuff[0],length(bbuff));
```

I don't know why, can someone explain for me?

Comment: Reading changes the position of the stream.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you call `WriteBuffer` or `ReadBuffer` the pointer to the position you are currently at the stream is moved forward by `length(...)`. Therefore moving the position back to 0 (Have a look at the `Seek` method of `TStream`, see documentation [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TStream.Seek)) your code is working.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know why, can someone explain for me?

Every `TStream` descendant has a `Position` property which indicates at what byte position in the stream a following read or write operation will take place. For each read or write operation the `Position` is advanced with the number of bytes read or written. To change the `Position` you can either assign to `Position` or call the `Seek()` function directly (`Position` uses internally the `Seek()` function).

Let's look at these three lines of your code:

```
  // At this point both hdevi.Position and bfile.Position are 0
  hdevi.ReadBuffer(hbuff[0],length(hbuff));
  // At this point hdevi.Position is 87040
  bfile.ReadBuffer(bbuff[0],length(bbuff));
  // now bfile.Position is 512
  // hdevi.Position is of course still 87040, alas, that's where the bbuff is written
  hdevi.WriteBuffer(bbuff[0],length(bbuff));
  // hdevi.Position is now 87040 + 512 = 87552
```

Obviously you wanted to write the 512 bytes from `bbuff` to the beginning of `hdevi`.
As you have found out you can either skip the reading into `hbuff` altogether (in which case `hdevi.Position` is at 0) or if you need to read the `hbuff` buffer first, you must reset the `hdevi.Position` to 0.